# How to apply TensorFlow Text Classification on new dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following this tutorial:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification_with_hub

It only goes up to fitting the model but I couldn't find how to use the model on a new dataset to classify unlabeled data. I tried following other tutorials but I couldn't get them to work since they might not be text based.

`model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))`
I run into an issue where I try to set the layer to 2 for positive, negative but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the purpose of that tutorial. That tutorial is applying the use of what is known as "transfer learning". Transfer Learning is when you take an already trained model, and train it with other data. What you are doing is creating an entirely new model, which is not the purpose of that specific tutorial. Furthermore, for that model you need a labeled dataset, which is provided in the tutorial using the Tensorflow Datasets library. To accomplish what you are trying to do, you must look at a different tutorial explaining how to train an LSTM model for text classification from scratch.